# How to find multiplicative inverses in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]=\{  a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} :  a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ a field?

How to find the multiplicative inverse of the above expression $a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}$ ( if $a$, $b$, $c$ are not all $0$)?

Comment: Have you thought about looking at x*y=1 and  solving for the simultaneous equations?

Comment: Also interesting is that there's a canonical way to invert power series, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Inverting_series

In your case the inverted power series will contract to a polynomial. Presumably you'll be able to write 1/(a+b\cuberoot{2} + c\cuberoot{4}) as a power series where the coefficients for the cuberoots are geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that  $\mathbb{Q}\bigl[\sqrt[3]{2}\bigr]$ is the image of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ under the evaluation homomorphism 
\begin{align}
\phi\colon \mathbb{Q}[X] &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
p &\mapsto p(\sqrt[3]{2})\,.
\end{align}

Then $\mathbb{Q}\bigl[\sqrt[3]{2}\bigr]$ is a field and equal to $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[3]{2}\bigr)$ (this is an application of the isomorphism theorem, see [Judson: *Abstract Algebra*](http://abstract.ups.edu/), Proposition 21.4).

The inverse of $$a + b\sqrt[3]{2} +c \sqrt[3]{4} \in \mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[3]{2}\bigr)$$ is 
$$ u + v\sqrt[3]{2} +w \sqrt[3]{4}$$
with rational
\begin{align}
u &= (a^2 - 2 b c)/D\\
v &= (2 c^2 - a b )/D\\
w &= (b^2 - a c)/D
\end{align}
where $D = a^3 + 2 b^3 - 6 a b c + 4 c^3$.